# Create a unix symbolic link from windows (preferable through python)

Tags: windows, unix

Don't ask why but for some reason I need to create a unix symbolic on a network drive (which is on linux computer) from a windows machine (that is where the script will run from).

Does anybody know if this is possible? If there is someway to force `python` to create this unix-based file?

The only other option would be to `ssh` from python to the unix machine and run the `ln -s ...` command from there, but that seems such a lot of hassle for something quite simple.

Comment: What sort of network drive?  That is, what protocol?

Comment: It is nfs filesytem on a linux server.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [CreateSymbolicLink function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363866.aspx) in the Windows API, but I don't know if it works on remote filesystems and I don't know how to call it from Python.

Comment: It needs to be an unix/linux type of symbolic link, I think this will create a windows type which doesn't work on unix unfortunately.

Comment: @kasper_o, I wouldn't dismiss it out of hand. It could be that when Windows sees that it's going to a network drive it converts it to some generic network "make a link" request, which then gets fulfilled by Unix on the other side.

Comment: I tried it with the commandline mklink tool from windwos and that one doesn't work, so I figured that the API function also wouldn't work, but do you think that it may function differently?

Comment: @kasper_o I suspect you're right and the command line just calls the function. Sorry I couldn't help.